# RxJava generic method to check error messages in subscriber

Tags: android, generics, rx-java

In my `Android` project, I do a lot of network requests (using `Retrofit`and `RxJava`), which return as response a custom supertype of response, which can consist of a valid or an error response.

```
AppResponse {  
   error=AppError {  
      code=12345,
      message='null'
   },
   data=null
}
```

The error codes are no HTTP error codes, but content retrieved from parsing the `XML` result with `SimpleXML`. There are about 4-5 error codes that are the same for all network requests, for example session is timed out or so. Therefore I would to write a generic method that checks all responses for these error codes and sets countermeasures like requesting a new session.

First I thought about using the `OkHttp`Interceptor, but because I need to parse my results to the proper format, I cannot use it.
I'm using `RxJava`after parsing the result and currently I'm checking the response of my result in the subscribe method.

```
    restClient.requestHostList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<HostListResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(HostListResponse hostListResponse) {
                    if (hostListResponse.isError()) {

                        if(hostListResponse.getError().getCode() == 12345) {
                            requestNewSession();
                        } else if(hostListResponse.getError().getCode() == 23456) {
                            requestNewLogin();
                        }
                   else {
                            //do some UI stuff here
                        }
```

I'm not sure how to proceed here, is there something like a `Transformer` that can be used in subscribe to verify the result and maybe start another network request or would it be better to start this before reaching the subscriber? I was also thinking if onErrorResumeNext() would be an option by making the Observable throw an error when it doesn't pass the result code test, something like this:

```
restClient.requestHostList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(new Func1<HostListResponse, Observable<Throwable>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Throwable> call(HostListResponse hostListResponse) {
                        if (hostListResponse.isError()) {
                            if(hostListResponse.getError().getCode() == 12345) {
                                throw new Exception();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Throwable>>() {
                    //do error handling here
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last solution is ok. Throwing exception in error case is absolutely normal behaviour. You can use `compose` operator to wrap your error handling logic and reuse it with all retrofit observables:

```
static final int NO_ERROR = 0;
static final int ERROR_A = 13;
static final int ERROR_B = 666;

Observable<BaseResponse> responseObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<BaseResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super BaseResponse> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(new BaseResponse(ERROR_A));
        //subscriber.onNext(new BaseResponse(ERROR_B));
        //subscriber.onNext(new BaseResponse(NO_ERROR));
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
});

responseObservable
        .compose(Utils.applyErrorHandler())//apply to this observable error handling logic
        .subscribe(baseResponse -> {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }, throwable -> {
            System.out.println("error:" + throwable);
        });
```

Utils class which handles errors:

```
public static class Utils {
    static Observable.Transformer schedulersTransformer = new Observable.Transformer<BaseResponse, BaseResponse>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<BaseResponse> call(Observable<BaseResponse> observable) {
            return observable.doOnNext(baseResponse -> {
                if (baseResponse.errorCode == ERROR_A) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error A");
                } else if (baseResponse.errorCode == ERROR_B) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error B");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyErrorHandler() {
        return (Observable.Transformer<T, T>) schedulersTransformer;
    }
}
```

Basic idea is to apply `Transformer` function to observable which calls `doOnNext` on each item, checks error codes and throws appropriate exception. In my example it's wrapped into static helper class `Utils` but it depends on your requirements, `Transformer` function could be injected via `Dagger` and replaced with tests transform function for instance.

You can read more about `compose` operator in `Dan Lew` blog post: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try that immediately :)